# jQuery hide and Django form widget

Tags: jquery, django

I'm using some jQuery code to hide and show a select in a form base on some circumstances. Everything it's fine, but I would like start the widget as hidden when the form is loaded the first time.

The jQuery hide/show manipulate the `style` of the select. When is hidden: `display: hidden;` when is shown: `display: block;`.

Is there a way to change the `attr` on the Django widget to add the `style="display: hidden;"`?

In the init of my form:

```
self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({..})
```

Is possible to set the style using the `attr`?

Answer (score 2):

I know you can do it with classes, I believe the syntax is like this:

```
self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'hide'});
```

I'm assuming it would work with the style attribute too, if it does it should be something like this, but I'm not able to test it right now:

```
self.fields['state'].widget.attrs.update({'style': 'display:none'});
```

The class route is probably better anyway, you'd just need to create a `.hide { display: none; }` class in your CSS.